# Kubernates cluster instance

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

I have created a Kubernetes cluster and one of instance in the cluster is inactive
I want to review the configured Kubernetes Engine cluster of an inactive configuration by which command should I check?
Should I use this "kubectl config get-contexts"?
or 
kubectl config use-context and kubectl config view?

Am beginner to cloud please anyone explains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kubectl config get-context` will not help you debug why the instance is failing. Basically it will just show you the list ot contexts.  A `context`  is a group of cluster access parameters. Each context contains a Kubernetes cluster, a user, and a namespace. The `current context` is the cluster that is currently the default for `kubectl` . On other hand the `kubectl config view` will just print you `kubeconfig` settings.

The best way to start is the [Kubernestes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/). It provides a good basic steps for troubleshoouting your cluster. Some of the steps can be applied to GKE as well as the Kubeadm or Minikube clusters.

If you're using GKE, then you can read the nodes logs from Stackdriver. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) is excellent start when you want to check the logs directly in the log viewer.

If one of your instaces report `NotReady` after listing them with `kubectl get nodes` I suggest to ssh to that instances and check kubernetes components (`kubelet` and `kube-proxy`). You can view the GKE nodes from the instances page.

**Kube  Proxy logs:**

```
/var/log/kube-proxy.log
```

If you want to check the `kubelet` logs, they're a unit in `systemd` in COS that can be accessed using jorunactl.

**Kubelet logs:**

```
sudo journalctl -u kubelet
```

For further debugging it is worth mentioning that that GKE master is a node inside a Google managed project and it is different from your cluster project. 
For the detailed master logs you will have open a google support ticket. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture) is more information about how GKE cluster architecture works, in case there's something related to the api-server.

Let me know if that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command to check status of all the nodes of a kubernetes cluster. Pleases note if you are using GKE managed service you will not be able to see status of master nodes, you will only see status of worker nodes.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
kubectl describe node nodename
```

You can also run below command to check status of control plane components.

```
kubectl get componentstatus
```

Comment: The last command is working well with very generic cluster configuration and going to be deprecated sooner or later: https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/553

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to get list of all the nodes in GKE cluster:

> `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

Once you have the list of nodes, you can describe the node to get the events"

> `kubectl describe node <Node-Name>`

Based on the events you can debug the node.